# Recent log messages

Tags: 7, database, log-messages

Is there a way to view more than just the "recent" log messages in Drupal 7?

I need to look further back for a customer, but the "recent" is only showing messages for today.

Is it possible to search a date range or something?

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Thank You!!
Nicole

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drupal only stores a limited number of log entries, determined by the *"Database log messages to keep"* setting located at Administration > Configuration > Development.

However, most web servers keep a so called "access log", a file containing an entry for each URL that was requested.

In some cases and configurations the information (e.g. who created a user) can be inferred from the access log.

Answer (score 2):

If you're referring to the logs at `/admin/reports/dblog` - what you see is all that is available.

Depending on your server configuration, you can likely find some more info in your php error logs, the location and the amount of data the error log stores varies based on the server configuration.

Answer (score 1):

To view more than the Recent log messages at `admin/reports/dblog` you need to use the error log or/and the access log of the webserver.

I'm not sure if in your case is Apache, NGINX or if you are using a webhosting service, some of them have an option to check this logs.

In the future, if you want to keep more messages at `admin/reports/dblog`, you can adjust that at `admin/config/development/logging` and increase the amount on the "Database log messages to keep" option. **Careful** with this option, a value like "1000000" could have a negative impact on the website performance.

If you don't have a shared hosting environment and you have ssh access to the webserver, I think the **best option** is to enable the [syslog module](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/syslog). This module logs events by sending messages to the logging facility of your web server's operating system (syslog).